# Update single value in Firebase Realtime Database using Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, firebase-realtime-database, proyecto26.restclient

I am using rest API for my project. I am trying to update a single value in users but having a hard time achieving this.

I keep getting the following error:

> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Proyecto26.RequestHelper'

Here is an image of how the data is stored in the firebase database:

[image: image of user data]

This error occurs on the following line.

```
 RestClient.Put($"{databaseURL}users/{userId}/{nodeUpdate}:{valueUpte}.json").Then(response =>
```

However, if I do the following the error does go away but the update does not go through. I believe I am missing something that will allow the update to go through.

```
 RestClient.Put($"{databaseURL}users/{userId}/{nodeUpdate}:{valueUpte}.json","").Then(response =>
```

I have read the documentation and so I proceeded to do the following approach below. It does update the database under that particular user id however, it removes the rest of the nodes that I have for the user and creates default nodes [after the update is made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgH47.png).

```
 public static void UpdateUserInfo(string userId, string nodeUpdate, string valueUpte, UpdateUserInfoCallback callback)
{
    Debug.Log("UpdateUserInfo Method");

    RestClient.Put($"{databaseURL}users/{userId}.json", (nodeUpdate,valueUpte)).Then(response =>
    {
        callback();
        Debug.Log("The user info was successfully updated in the database");
    });
}
```

I have also tried doing the following approach but this does not update the data:

```
  RestClient.Put($"{databaseURL}users/{userId}/{nodeUpdate}.json", (valueUpte)).Then(response =>
    {
        callback();
        Debug.Log("The user info was successfully updated in the database");
    });
```

**Update: Was able to resolve issue by using JSON.Net to update value's. **

Comment: That error doesn't look familiar to me. Can you reproduce the problem by calling the REST API directly in the address bar of a browser, instead of in C# code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: I am not sure how to do that. I will look into that and send you what I am seeing shortly. I am fairly new to this

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have provided more info on where this error is occurring. I hope this helps

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the values of `userId`, `nodeUpdate`, and `valueUpte`? It is most likely that someone can help if you reproduce the problem with hard-coded values for all variables.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for that suggestion. I have updated the question with the hard-coded examples of the values. Essentially userID is the id of the user, the nodeUpdate would be the child that holds the value, and valueUpt is the value that I am update of that child.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated my question with the different approaches I attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have another look at the documentation for the [REST API of the Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data). You'll need to pass the value that is to be written as JSON in the body of the request, and not in the URL as you are trying.

Comment: I will read it once more the documentation. Thank you for you help

Comment: I have read the documentation and I am not quite understanding how to update data. I understand I need to pass the value in JSON in the body of the request but not seeing how to do that.

Comment: `RestClient.Put($"{databaseURL}users/14.json", "{email:"new email"}"`?

Comment: I have tried that but it does not appear to work. I have tried hard coding it as such but it does not work

Comment: Please show *that* hardcoded approach in your question.

Comment: Was able to figure it out the update. However, I do have a question: Why is the int value in my JSON updating to 0 if I am targeting a different child?

Comment: If you call `RestClient.Put($"{databaseURL}users/{userId}.json"`, all of `/users/$userId` is replaced with whatever value you pass in. If you want to only replace the values whose keys you pass in, use `Patch()` instead of `Put()`.

Comment: I was able to do the update using JSON.Net. I have posted what I have done so far.

Comment: Should I ask a new question regarding this weird behavior

Comment: Yeah, it read like a new problem, so I'd recommend rolling back the change here, and posting a new question for someone to look at.

Comment: Thank you. Will do that @Frank van Puffelen